# Populate html dropdown menu form database

Tags: php, html

I want to populate a dropdown menu from a database. I've already tried some methods but none of them works fine. My code looks like this:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=1***7;dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password');

$sql = "SELECT user FROM users where tip='tip1'";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

$users = $stmt->fetchAll();

?>

<select>
    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
        <option value="<?= $user['user']; ?>"></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

I usually can see the dropdown menu,but no items are displayed like in the picture below.[image]

Comment: You assign only value... try this: `<option value="<?= $user['user']; ?>"><?= $user['user']; ?></option>`

Comment: look at your HTML source; what do you see?

Comment: ...well there you go. Guess what you didn't do?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to echo inside option `<option value="<?= $user['user']; ?>"><?= $user['user']; ?></option>`

```
<select>
    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
        <option value="<?= $user['user']; ?>"><?= $user['user']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```